# iOS: Call segue from coded UIViewController outside of Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a custom UIVieController class that it's not included in any StoryBoard,  I need to call from this class an UIViewController that is included in a StoryBoard, I tried many ways to do this but it doesn't work, always get a NSException because when I try to instance the UIViewController of the StoryBoard and get a nil object.

I don't know why it's happening this, I really appreciate any help with this.

Thank you.

Just to clarify in this code I omitted the pushing of the view to the UINavigationController.

I tried this.

```
+(void)loadSocialMediaAppSegue:(AXISAppDelegate*)delegate withName:(NSString*)segueId{


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    AXISWebViewViewController *axisWebView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:segueId];    

}
```

and this

```
+(void)loadSocialMediaAppSegue:(AXISAppDelegate*)delegate withName:(NSString*)segueId{

    AXISWebViewViewController *axisWebView = [delegate.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:segueId];

}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you tried which did not produce the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the first thing you need to do is to add a `identifier` to you view controller at Storyboard, you can do that opening the Storyboard's Identity Inspector and fill the storyboard id field.

Now you are able to call this UIViewController from any place you want like this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"the name of your storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"the id of your view controller"];
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I Just needed to add the identifier to the UIViewController and I was creating the identifier for the segue so it was the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code you are using to instantiate the VC from the Storyboard.

In general:

To instantiate a View Controller from StoryBoard:

```
MyViewController *MyVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
```

Make sure you set the Storyboard ID and Restoration ID and Class name to "MyViewController" or whatever you want to call it and use that as the parameter for instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

Then if you are in a navigation controller, simply push the instantiated view controller onto the navigation stack:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:MyVC animated:YES];
```

or present it modally:

```
[self presentViewController:MyVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```